# How can i calculate second array index no position?

Tags: java, arrays

```
//second highest from an array ,To find out the second maximum array element from an array
import java.util.*;
public  class Secondhighest
{
    public static void main(String h[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Array Size");
        int firstmax,secondmax,firstpos=0,secondpos=0;
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        int num[]=new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter Array  Elements");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            num[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Display Array Elements");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Array Elements are:-"+num[i]+" at poition no"+i);
        }
        System.out.println("Checking of Second Highest No");
        firstmax=num[0];secondmax=num[0];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(num[i]>firstmax)
            {
                secondmax=firstmax;
                firstmax=num[i];
                firstposition=i+1;
            }

            else if(num[i]>secondmax)
            {
                secondmax=num[i];
                secondpos=i+1;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("First Max number is :-"+firstmax+"At position no:-"+firstpos);
        System.out.println("Second Max number is :-"+secondmax+"At position no:-"+secondpos);
    }
}
```

Here is my code snippet ,I have to calculate second largest number in array ,by using this logic i can find out second maximum element but i am not able to find out the second position of array

Comment: Inside the condition: `if(num[i]>firstmax)` you forgot to update `secondpos`

Comment: So what is this code there for?  Is there a problem with it?  If so, what is it?  If not, why is it there?

Answer (score 0):

Since the array of yours isn't sorted, you have to go through every position and compare its value. I also assume that you don't want the highest and second highest value to be equal, so I added `num[i] != firstmax`, where I check if the number at position `i` is not equal to the max value.

Since you want the index position, you don't want to add `+1`, since Java uses zero-based indexing (meaning everything starts at 0). Adding `+1` to that will give you the position above the value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (num[i] > firstmax) {
        secondmax = firstmax;
        firstmax = num[i];
        firstpos = i; // changed from "firstposition=i+1;"
    } // removed else
    if (num[i] > secondmax && num[i] != firstmax) {
        secondmax = num[i];
        secondpos = i; // changed from "secondpos=i+1;"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Array Size
5
Enter Array  Elements
3
5
4
1
2
[...]
Checking of Second Highest No
First Max number is: 5, at position no: 1
Second Max number is: 4, at position no: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

use Arrays.sort to sort the arrays.. in your case

```
public static void main(String h[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Array Size");
        int firstmax,secondmax,firstpos=0,secondpos=0;
        int size=sc.nextInt();
        int num[]=new int[size];
        Arrays.sort(num); // will do the sorting 
        //print the array contents
        for(int n:num) { System.out.println(n);}
    }
```